# incompatible character encodings: Windows-1252 and UTF-8 yml files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf8-decode

I am using Apatana Studio 3.0. The non-ASCII characters, such as  `ü`, is available in de.yml and oher files. Should they require extra encoding values? I have  `# encoding: utf-8` present in specific controllers and it works well for all the pages apart from index.html.erb. The index.html.erb raises errors:

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError in Home#index
    incompatible character encodings: Windows-1252 and UTF-8
```

The translation string in `de.yml` is:

```
de:
    display_eula: EULA für Applikation
```

NOTE:
The string above is rendered correctly on other pages, it is just not working for `index.html.erb`.

Comment: I cleaned up your question to make it more readable. It's not important to try to break the question into separate parts, just write clearly and concisely. Also, your editor isn't important in this issue if it's generating your source so Ruby can read it.

Comment: how could i stop you from fiddling around with my question? haha Thanks

Comment: "how could i stop you from fiddling around with my question?" By writing it clearly and concisely. ;-) Seriously, SO wants to be the Wikipedia of programming so think of getting the information into people's heads as quickly as possible so they can formulate answers as quickly as possible, all in a comfortable "encyclopedic" writing style.

Comment: so where is your answer, I am waiting for one ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between the character encoding of the source script, and I/O being performed on files read from disk and other sources.

The magic lines like `# encoding: utf-8` tell Ruby the source file itself has UTF-8 encoded characters outside the normal ASCII range. That lets Ruby interpret fixed strings and multibyte characters in the source file correctly.

For I/O streams you'll need to tell Ruby how to interpret the incoming/outgoing data. [`IO.new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-new) and its related methods take an optional parameter saying what the incoming/outgoing data stream encoding is.

YAML, JSON, HTML, XML and other file types that are read from disk, socket or pipe are susceptible to encoding problems if they are not pure ASCII. Ruby has a pretty good suite of tools for converting on the fly, or doing it once the string is in memory. If you don't tell Ruby what to expect, or don't convert to what it expects, it'll complain, like you saw.

James Gray has a series of [articles](http://blog.grayproductions.net/categories/character_encodings) talking about dealing with Unicode and multibyte character sets in Ruby. It gets into some deep water because it's not an easy topic but he does a nice job explaining things.

Comment: the problem was with the data coming from AWS- SimpleDB (which required to be changed to `string.encode("utf-8")`. Nonetheless thank you for your effort.

Comment: That makes sense. Any source of text outside your control should be considered suspicious these days. Multi-byte characters have solved some problems, but caused a number of other ones we'll never get rid of.

Answer (score 2):

the problem was with the data coming from AWS- SimpleDB (which required to be changed to `string.encode("utf-8")`. Nonetheless thank you for your effort.